# How to make an annotation tensor with inconsistent number of objects per image?

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, tensorflow-datasets

I was following [this tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/colab_tutorials/eager_few_shot_od_training_tf2_colab.ipynb) from [tf/models/research/object_detection/colab_tutorials](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection/colab_tutorials) where the author uses TF object detection API to fine-tune a RetinaNet model trained on COCO dataset to detect another class.

Unfortunately, my dataset has multiple objects on each image and the number of objects is not consistent, i.e. an image might have 1-11 traffic lights. My localization tensor has shape `(Number_of_images, None, 4)`  and my classification tensor has shape `(Number_of_images, None, 2)`.

How to pass inconsistent tensor to the TF model such that it does not overwrite the graph on each iteration?